# Adding words to spellchecker dictionary in NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, spell-checking

My NetBeans dictionary is kind of... illiterate? It's flagging words like "website" and the "doesn" part of `doesn't`. I right-clicked expecting to see your standard `Add to dictionary...` option but found none. I browsed the menus and also found nothing.

How do I educate my NetBeans spellchecker?

Comment: Ironically, the NetBeans spellchecker flags the word "NetBeans" as misspelled.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It looks like the spell checker is a relatively recent addition. There are basic instructions on how to change the dictionary [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/spellchecker).

Adding an unknown word to the dictionary requires `alt + enter` while the cursor is on the 'misspelled' word. This might take care of the most glaring omissions.

If it highlights just 'doesn', then it probably isn't aware of English-style contractions (i.e., it doesn't know that words can span across an apostrophe). Until that is fixed, I would recommend just adding 'doesn' as a separate word using the above method.

Comment: Oldie but goodie response. Seven years later, Search/Help still doesn't offer this solution. Derp.

Comment: @TonyG true, but it's a minor annoyance compared to reams and reams of bug reports and glitches and impossible to find configuration options in the *Competitor Who Shall Not Be Named*.